# I have trouble "jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-core"

Tags: gtk, makefile, mismatch, jhbuild

First I wanted download gtk on my mac. 
so I try this step. http://www.gtk.org/download/macos.php
When I tried "jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-core", my mac raise error.
Help me!!!

```
    libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.2, but the
    libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.
    libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.2
    libtool: and run autoconf again.
    make[4]: *** [GdkQuartzView.lo] Error 63
    make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.2, but the
    libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.
    libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.2
    libtool: and run autoconf again.
    make[4]: *** [gdkapplaunchcontext-quartz.lo] Error 63
    libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.2, but the
    libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.
    libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.2
    libtool: and run autoconf again.
    make[4]: *** [gdkcursor-quartz.lo] Error 63
    libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.2, but the
    libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.
    libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.2
    libtool: and run autoconf again.
    make[4]: *** [GdkQuartzWindow.lo] Error 63
    libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.2, but the
    libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.
    libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.2
    libtool: and run autoconf again.
    make[4]: *** [gdkcolor-quartz.lo] Error 63
    make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It's my log

Comment: It's telling you exactly what to do - what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on SnowLeopard (10.6), however not in MountainLion (10.8), 
you have to install version 2.4.2, http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/
download the archive, extract and then configure and install using:

```
./configure --prefix /Users/YourUserName/gtk/inst 
make 
make install
```

Where `/Users/YourUserName/gtk/inst` has to be the folder you are installing gtk in.

Then jhbuild your gtk ;)